# They are scary looking vs they are looking scary

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between these two sentence

1.They are scary looking

2.They are looking scary

The second one I think scary is a subject complement in that they=scary

But I am not sure about the first one.

Comment: As Collins say lists 'nice-looking' and 'foul-tasting' as compound adjectives, 'scary looking' might well be supposed to be another example. In 'They are looking scary', the simplex adjective follows the present continuous.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Oh that makes sense

Comment: @Fernando Martinez : The example doesn't employ a compound adjective, which a compound word is two words made into a single word.  The example uses two separate words "looking" and "scary," which is not the same thing as "looking-scary."  If "looking-scary" were a word, then it would mean that in this context, but "looking-scary" is not a word, not a compound adjective.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But to all intents they mean the same thing, as in *It's a rain-threatening sky* and *The sky is threatening rain*. Same meaning, but parsed differently.

Comment: @WS2 But OP goes on to mention that he is interested in the grammar. // I agree with Hot Licks that in this particular case, there are subtle differences in the semantics.

Answer (score 3):

"They are scary looking" might be (seriously) applied to anything from a group of numbers to some people outside your car in a bad section of town at 3AM.

"They are looking scary" might be similarly applied, but it carries the connotation that what was previously not so scary has gotten so -- the situation has gotten worse.

Comment: But *scary looking* could also include things that have just become scary, but it would need to be determined by other other context. e.g. *this months sales figures are scary looking* implies that in other months they have not been. But *the sales figures are looking scary* is indication by itself that a change for the worse (if that's what scary implies) has taken place.

Answer (score 0):

"They are scary looking" indicates a general and permanent quality of whatever "they" are.

"They are looking scary" indicates that they are indeed scary now, but I think there is an implication that this is true only in the present, and it is not a permanent condition; hence the use of present continuous.

Answer (score -1):

"1.They are scary looking" is correct ("scary-looking" can also be hyphenated for clarity or when it precedes another noun, as in "Those are scary-looking masks.")

"2.They are looking scary" isn't idiomatic and doesn't quite make sense, at least by itself. To quote commenter WS2 (below), "These sales figures are so bad they are looking scary," would be fine. But do you mean to say, "They are looking *scared*"? Otherwise, one would normally say, "They look frightened," or (depending on your meaning), "They look frightening!"

Comment: I think you can say that if "they are beginning to look scary" (or even "they have a quality of appearing to be scary") is sensible, then "they are looking scary" should be sensible too.

Comment: These sales figures are so bad they are *looking scary*.

Comment: @WS2- Thank you. I have added your example to my answer.